# matplotlib heatmap scaled color map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a heatmap to visualize the value of a cost function. The parameter space is built from logspaced values for the x axis and linearly spaced values for the y axis. My goal is to reduce the contrast in the color scheme

```
hm = ax5.pcolor(gs, cmap = "Greens",vmin=gs.min().min(), vmax=gs.max().max())
```

[image]

As it can be seen, the scored range from -0.4 to 1, so we have non positive numbers and standard log normalization in Matplotlib won't work. I also tried with `SymLogNorm` but results are not improved but quite the contrary. For the linthresh parameter I picked the min positive value from my scores

```
 hm = ax5.pcolor(gs, cmap = "Greens", norm= SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.0013, linscale=1))
```

[image]

How can properly implement the log scale?

Comment: Do you want to reduce or to increase the contrast of the image? (usually we want to increase the contrast) Did you try using non-monochrome [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html)?

Comment: since I have a peak in score, the dark region loses comparability since the presence of a peak broadens the range of possible colors, flattening the middle region. I honestly don't know if what I just said translates into increasing or decreasing contrast lol, but hopefully this gives you a better idea of what I want

Comment: non monochrome colormaps have the same issue, since the coloring is done in a linear fashion

Comment: What I would do is to re-norm the values by hand between 0 and 1. Then, try to apply different non-linear function (sqrt, square, tan)... or simply setting `vmax=0.8*gs.max().max()` isn't working for example?